# Euro symbol not shown properly

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I am loading a csv file (UTF-8) with VBA QueryTable to excel.
The Euro currency symbol is shown as Ôé¼
This is because the CSV file has no ANSI encoding and Excel cannot read non-English characters.
I have used the code

```
worksheet.Columns("C").NumberFormat = "# €_)"
```

to change the currency for the column but it does not change the Ôé¼  from the csv file.
It changes after I type a new number..
Is there an easy solution?

A sample of my CSV is:

```
"Project Name","Project Description","Project Budget"
"000 TEST","ABC Project Register","500000 €"
"001 TEST","DEF Project Register","400000 €"
"002 TEST","GHI Project Register","800000 €"
```

Comment: A number format never change the *content* of a cell. As long as Excel cannot read your input as a number, changing the format will not do anything. Btw: what is `Ôé¼` supposed to be?

Comment: Ôé¼ is supposed to be €

Comment: Can you provide a sample from the the csv file? (if nothing is sensitive)

Comment: Have you [added `CharacterSet=65001`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33820866/11683) to your QueryTable's connection string?

Comment: Yes you are right! I changed in QueryTables the property ".TextFilePlatform = 850"  to 65001 and it works now.. Thank you very much